# How to decouple range selector with input Box in highcharts?

Tags: highcharts

Is it possible to hide the range selector but the input(dates) box should be visible and should allow us to provide the to and from date range? Any API reference will be of great help.Thanks

Comment: Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/stock/navigator/enabled/ ?

Comment: **API reference here**: https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/navigator.enabled

Comment: Ask here is to disable the zoom panel (1m , 3m etc) and ONLY ENABLE THE INPUT BOX. Both are enabled in jsfiddle shared.

Answer (score 0):

Just use CSS

```
.highcharts-range-selector-buttons {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```